# htaccess not behaving like expected

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I'm creating an htaccess with which I want to achieve 3 things:

- remove trailing slash
- redirect all requests that aren't `css`, `ico`, `jpg`, `js`, `php` or `png` files to index.php
- redirect all files to view.php if the query string doesn't begin with `a`

At the moment it looks like this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /test/
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1 [N]                                  # remove trailing slash

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(css|ico|jpg|js|php|png)$     # if it isn't one of the files
RewriteRule . "index.php" [L]                               # then redirect to index

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^a($|&)                        # if query doesn't start with a
RewriteRule . "view.php" [L]                                # then redirect to view
```

This way, the following test cases should be true:

```
http://127.0.0.1/test/contact               ->         http://127.0.0.1/test/index.php
http://127.0.0.1/test/contact/              ->         http://127.0.0.1/test/index.php
http://127.0.0.1/test/contact.png           ->         http://127.0.0.1/test/view.php
http://127.0.0.1/test/contact.png?a         ->         http://127.0.0.1/test/contact.png?a
```

When I try these out on [this site](http://htaccess.mwl.be/), it shows me exactly these results.
In practice, however, when I'm trying out URLs, It completely breaks:

```
http://127.0.0.1/test/contact               ->         http://127.0.0.1/test/view.php
http://127.0.0.1/test/contact/              ->         Error 500
http://127.0.0.1/test/contact.png           ->         http://127.0.0.1/test/view.php
http://127.0.0.1/test/contact.png?a         ->         http://127.0.0.1/test/contact.png?a
```

It seems as if the script always looks at the query-related part first, although with that in mind, it still doesn't make much sense to me that `/contact/` breaks. When I remove the query-related part though, the rest does work.

Did I forget about something? Is there a rule concerning the order of operation that I'm not aware of? Did I make a typo?

All input is appreciated!

**P.S.** I know that I will have to add a query that starts with an `a` for all local images, stylesheets, scripts and AJAX-calls. I'm doing this so that when people view media in a separate tab, I can create a fancy page around it, allowing people to navigate through all the media that is publicly present on the server.

Comment: Could you enable and post the debug logs for the rewrite module ([RewriteLog and RewriteLogLevel](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritelog) for apache 2.2,
[LogLevel](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#logging) for apache 2.4) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Issues with your code:**

1. First all non-css/js/image requests are routed to `index.php` and then anything without `?a` is routed to `view.php` so eventually `index.php` won't be used at all. You need to use a negated condition in last rule for anything that doesn't have `.php` extension..
2. `mod_rewrite` syntax doesn't allow inline comments.
3. You need `R` flag in first rule to change URL in browser.

You can use this code in `/test/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /test/

# if not a directory then remove trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ $1 [L,NE,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(css|ico|jpe?g|js|php|png)$
RewriteRule . index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)a [NC]
RewriteRule !\.php$ view.php [L,NC]
```

Comment: It works now, but how can it be that the query-related part is being read when the L flag is used in the file-related part?

Comment: `L` flag doesn't stop other rules to execute. It just causes `mod_rewrite` loop to run again. (It works as `continue` in a `while` loop not a `break`)

Comment: Accepted because you solved the problem flawlessly. I do have another question, if you don't mind. Adding the `R` flag to the trailing slash rule doesn't update the browsers' URL. Do you know why?

Comment: `RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ $1 [L,R]` should definitely change URL in browser. Let me know if that's what you need and I will update the answer.

Comment: Because of the previous assumption I made about the `L` flag, I thought I had to let it out. Writing `RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ $1 [L,R]` indeed makes it work, so you can update it